# User-selected image file not showing in TImage component

Tags: delphi

I have this procedure that lets a user select an image file. Once selected, it should be displayed in a `TImage` component.

Why is it not showing (**even when the file path is shown in a label**)?

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btn1_select_imgClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  OpenDialog: TOpenDialog;
begin
  OpenDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  OpenDialog.Filter := 'All Files|*.*';
  OpenDialog.Options := [ofPathMustExist, ofFileMustExist];
  try
    if OpenDialog.Execute then
    begin
      lbl_selected_file.Caption := OpenDialog.FileName;
      img1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
      OriginalImage := TBitmap.Create;
      OriginalImage.Assign(img1.Picture.Bitmap);
    end;
  finally
    OpenDialog.Free;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Full code:

```pascal
unit image_blurrr_unit;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg;

var
  OriginalImage: TBitmap;
  PixellatedImage: TBitmap;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1_select_img: TButton;
    btn2_select_output_path: TButton;
    lbl_selected_file: TLabel;
    lbl_output_path: TLabel;
    img1: TImage;
    pnl_img: TPanel;
    pnl_btns: TPanel;
    procedure btn1_select_imgClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2_select_output_pathClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btn1_select_imgClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  OpenDialog: TOpenDialog;
begin
  OpenDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  OpenDialog.Filter := 'All Files|*.*';
  OpenDialog.Options := [ofPathMustExist, ofFileMustExist];
  try
    if OpenDialog.Execute then
    begin
      lbl_selected_file.Caption := OpenDialog.FileName;
      img1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
      OriginalImage := TBitmap.Create;
      OriginalImage.Assign(img1.Picture.Bitmap);
    end;
  finally
    OpenDialog.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn2_select_output_pathClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileOpenDialog: TFileOpenDialog;
  OutputImage: TBitmap;
begin
  FileOpenDialog := TFileOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    FileOpenDialog.Options := [fdoPickFolders];
    FileOpenDialog.Title := 'Select Output Path';
    if FileOpenDialog.Execute then
    begin
      OutputImage := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        // Create a copy of the original image
        OutputImage.Assign(OriginalImage);

        // Apply the blur effect to the output image here...

        // Save the output image to the selected folder
        OutputImage.SaveToFile(FileOpenDialog.FileName + '\output.jpg');
      finally
        OutputImage.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FileOpenDialog.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the [`TPicture.Bitmap`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.Bitmap) documentation:

> If `Bitmap` is referenced when the picture contains a Metafile or Icon graphic <sup>1</sup>, the graphic won't be converted ([Types of Graphic Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Types_of_Graphic_Objects)). **Instead, the original contents of the picture are discarded and `Bitmap` returns a new, blank bitmap.**

<sup>1</sup>: just replace "a Metafile or Icon graphic" with "any non-BMP graphic".

So, if the user selects a non-`.bmp` file (which is likely the case, since `.bmp` files are rarely used nowadays, in favor of other file formats, like PNG), then accessing `img1.Picture.Bitmap` will wipe out the current image that has been loaded into `img1.Picture`, replaced with a blank `TBitmap` object (which you then assign to your `OriginalImage` object). That is why you don't see anything being displayed in the `TImage`.

The solution is to access the original loaded image via the [`TPicture.Graphic`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.Graphic) property, instead of the `TPicture.Bitmap` property, eg:

```
OriginalImage.Assign(img1.Picture.Graphic);
```

---

That being said, there is another problem with your code:

```
OutputImage.SaveToFile(FileOpenDialog.FileName + '\output.jpg');
```

`OutputImage` is a `TBitmap`, so its `SaveToFile()` method can only create a BMP-encoded file.  So, you are creating a BMP file with a `.jpg` file extension, which does not make it a valid JPG image.  To do that, you would need to use [`TJPEGImage`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage) instead of `TBitmap`, eg:

```
uses
  ..., Vcl.Imaging.jpeg;

procedure TForm1.btn2_select_output_pathClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileOpenDialog: TFileOpenDialog;
  BlurredImage: TBitmap;
  OutputImage: TJPEGImage;
begin
  FileOpenDialog := TFileOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    FileOpenDialog.Options := [fdoPickFolders];
    FileOpenDialog.Title := 'Select Output Path';
    if FileOpenDialog.Execute then
    begin
      BlurredImage := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        // Create a copy of the original image
        BlurredImage.Assign(OriginalImage);

        // Apply the blur effect to the output image here...

        // Save the output image to the selected folder
        OutputImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
        try
          OutputImage.Assign(BlurredImage);
          OutputImage.SaveToFile(FileOpenDialog.FileName + '\output.jpg');
        finally
          OutputImage.Free;
        end;
      finally
        BlurredImage.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FileOpenDialog.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

That said, if you want the output file to be in the same format as the input file, then you can do this instead:

```
var
  OriginalImage: TGraphic;
  OriginalExt: String;

...

procedure TForm1.btn1_select_imgClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  OpenDialog: TOpenDialog;
begin
  OpenDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  OpenDialog.Filter := 'All Files|*.*';
  OpenDialog.Options := [ofPathMustExist, ofFileMustExist];
  try
    if OpenDialog.Execute then
    begin
      lbl_selected_file.Caption := OpenDialog.FileName;
      img1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
      OriginalImage := TGraphicClass(img1.Picture.Graphic.ClassType).Create;
      OriginalImage.Assign(img1.Picture.Graphic);
      OriginalExt := ExtractFileExt(OpenDialog.FileName);
    end;
  finally
    OpenDialog.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn2_select_output_pathClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileOpenDialog: TFileOpenDialog;
  BlurredImage: TBitmap;
  OutputImage: TGraphic;
begin
  FileOpenDialog := TFileOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    FileOpenDialog.Options := [fdoPickFolders];
    FileOpenDialog.Title := 'Select Output Path';
    if FileOpenDialog.Execute then
    begin
      BlurredImage := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        // Create a copy of the original image
        BlurredImage.Assign(OriginalImage);

        // Apply the blur effect to the output image here...

        // Save the output image to the selected folder
        OutputImage := TGraphicClass(OriginalImage.ClassType).Create;
        try
          OutputImage.Assign(BlurredImage);
          OutputImage.SaveToFile(FileOpenDialog.FileName + '\output' + OriginalExt);
          // alternatively:
          // OutputImage.SaveToFile(FileOpenDialog.FileName + '\output.' + GraphicExtension(TGraphicClass(OutputImage.ClassType)));
        finally
          OutputImage.Free;
        end;
      finally
        BlurredImage.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FileOpenDialog.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Nice, catch. That opens other cases: what happens when user don't upload a jpg file or bitmap? I think I can do something with `with` keyword... but I've been advised against using `with` in any case... any recommendation?

Comment: @OmarGonzales `with` has nothing to do with this (and yes, you should avoid `with` in general). The `TPicture.Graphic` property will hold the loaded image in its original format (ie, `TBitmap` for BMP, `TGIFImage` for GIF, `TJPEGImage` for JPG, `TPNGImage` for PNG, etc). All of those formats are assignable to/from `TBitmap`. Loading and saving image files should be done with their native formats, but manipulating images in memory should usually be done with `TBitmap` (unless you *really* know what you are doing with the other native formats to manipulate them directly).

Comment: I was referring to: `OutputImage := TJPEGImage.Create;` so, you're creating a JPEG object... that wouldn't work if image is png, or would it?

Comment: In the code I showed, the user's file is loaded as-is into `TImage`, and is then `Assign()`'ed as-is to a `TBitmap`, which is then `Assign()`'ed to a `TJPEGImage` for output. It will work just fine. However, if you want the output file to be in the same format as the input file, that will take a little extra work involving the use of `Picture.Graphic.ClassType`.

Comment: Yes, for now this will work. But I'm interested on outputting same format as input... just to learn. May you point me to an example that doesn't use the `with` keyword?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of saving the output to the same format as the input file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that you can use **FMX.TBitmap** class in VCL application?

Why would anyone even consider using **FMX.TBitmap** in VCL application?

For one [FMX.TBitmap.LoadFromFile](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.LoadFromFile) class supports loading and saving of many image types with ease.

Another thing is that you can easily apply any number [FMX.Filter.Effects](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Filter.Effects) to the said **FMX Bitmap**.

The only problem is that there is no easy way of of loading FMX Bitmap to or from VCL components.

---

Here is a simple code example for adding Pixelate effect for chosen file that is then saved into another file

```
uses FMX.Graphics, FMX.Filter.Effects;

procedure TForm1.BtnOpenImageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OPenDialog1.FileName);
    OriginalFileName := OpenDialog1.FileName;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BtnSaveProcessedImageClick(Sender: TObject);
var FMXOriginalBitmap: FMX.Graphics.TBitmap;
    FMXProcessedBitmap: FMX.Graphics.TBitmap;
    FMXPixelateFilter: FMX.Filter.Effects.TFilterPixelate;
begin
  FMXOriginalBitmap := FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
  FMXOriginalBitmap.LoadFromFile(OriginalFileName);

  FMXPixelateFilter := FMX.Filter.Effects.TFilterPixelate.Create(nil);
  FMXPixelateFilter.Input := FMXOriginalBitmap;
  FMXPixelateFilter.BlockCount := 100;
  FMXProcessedBitmap := FMXPixelateFilter.Output;
  FMXProcessedBitmap.SaveToFile('D:\Proba.jpg');

  Image2.Picture.LoadFromFile('D:\Proba.jpg');
end;
```

Comment: I'm getting: `Cannot assign a TPJPEG image to a TBitmap image`.

Comment: That is because you are trying to assign VCL based JPEG image to FMX based Bitmap. When working with FMX Bitmaps you can use LoadFromFile to load any [supported image formats](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager#Supported_Image_Formats). No need use TJPEG or TPNG classes as you would have to in VCL.